# Does scikit learn provide an easier solution to getting a confidence level for the coefficient?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm working through Introduction to Statistical Learning, but I'm having trouble coming up with a confidence interval for the coefficient using scikit learn (I'm trying to replicate the code in Python).

```
X = df.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = df.iloc[:, 1].values


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=1/3, random_state = 0)


classifier = LinearRegression()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

#predciting on X_test
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)


print(r2_score(y_pred, y_test))

print(classifier.intercept_)
print(classifier.coef_)
```

Using standard deviation and 95% confidence level:

```
stdev = np.sqrt(sum((classifier.predict(X_train) - y_train)**2) / (len(y_train) - 2))


prediction = (y_pred - 1.96*stdev, y_pred + 1.96*stdev)
```

Using OLS:

```
ols = sm.OLS(X, y)
ols_result = ols.fit()
print(ols_result.summary())


print(ols_result.bse)



ci = classifier.coef_ + 2 * ols_result.bse
ci2 = classifier.coef_ - 2 * ols_result.bse

final_ci = ci + ci2
```

I get different results for both so I'm not entirely sure which one is more accurate. Any suggestions? Does scikit learn provide an easier solution to getting a confidence level for the coefficient?

Answer (score 0):

Check this. It looks like proper steps has been described below:

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/41934/obtaining-a-confidence-interval-for-the-prediction-of-a-linear-regression

Comment: I have looked at this, but I don't understand the section on prediction - 1.96*stdev. I tried the following--is this accurate?

ci1 = y_pred - 1.96*stdev

ci2 = y_pred + 1.96*stdev